# vlookup bug with dates

Tags: excel, vlookup, excel-2016

i want to use vlookup/sverweis to reference on specific dates (with exact match). Unfortunately the reference does not work, although the dates on both tables match exactly. Oddly enough it works when i go into the cell (B3) and hit enter.

Is this a known bug? How can i fix it, i dont want to go through each cell (>10000 values) and hit enter.

the image shows an example (SVERWEIS = VLOOKUP in German)

[image]

Comment: Recalculate with F9?

Comment: yes i tried, it doesn't work

Comment: This is known but can only occur if both dates are not **exactly** equal. Your datetime is `43466.625` and `=43466.625+0.00000000001` in another cell leads to be `Cell1 = Cell2` == `TRUE` because the difference is in 16th significant digit only. But `VLOOKUP` nevertheless does not take both cells as exactly the same.

Comment: yep, that seems to be the problem, thanks!

Comment: If you are not too concerned about time then this could also work - =vlookup(left(B3,10), E3:F3,2,false) or =vlookup(left(b3,16), E3:F3, 2,false) if every cell has time in DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM format

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but I have both dates in B3 and E3 formatted as date...

See:
[image: vlookup with dates]

Other tricks I have done and you could try is to:

1) do an edit/replace of the ",0)"  with ",0)*1" which should force a recalculation...

2) do an edit / replace of "=V" with "xyxyV" and then replace the xyxy with = ...

Edit: if the dates in the cells have odd spaces with them then you could change the formula as so:

```
=VLOOKUP(TRIM(B3),E3:F3,2,0)
```

The TRIM() function removes leading and trailing spaces...

Comment: i also have both dates formated as date in the exact same format. ... sry, it is not the cell C3 that i have to goto and hit enter but B3 (i corrected the question).

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue by doing an edit/replace in the date range (B3), searching for " " and replacing with " ". Somehow this did the trick.

Comment: It did the trick because you had a leading or trailing space with the date and not just the date, which meant the two dates were not identical...